# Why is new Win 10 install restarting slow, but booting fast after shutdown?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, shutdown

I have a desktop hp 6200. With Win7 pro everything functions as it should.  With win10 pro, if I restart the PC, I never see the hp splash screen and cannot access the bios.  After ~2.5 minutes win10 loads and everything works as it should..
If I shut down the machine, then turn it on it works as it should. I see the HP splash screen, can access the bios, and win10 loads in under a minute.

The issue seems to only be with restart.

I have tried with "Fast Startup" on and off, but get the same results.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What type of hard drive? SSD or spinning disc?

Comment: spinning mechanical hard drive

Comment: I would run a chkdsk /r on the C drive, see if it finds and corrects any file system or free space issues.